# simplify in declaring variables value in php

Tags: php

```
$jan5 = 0;
$feb5 = 0;
$mar5 = 0;
$apr5 = 0;
$may5 = 0;
$jun5 = 0;
$jul5 = 0;
$aug5 = 0;
$sep5 = 0;
$oct5 = 0;
$nov5 = 0;
$dec5 = 0;
$jan4 = 0;
$feb4 = 0;
$mar4 = 0;
$apr4 = 0;
$may4 = 0;
$jun4 = 0;
$jul4 = 0;
$aug4 = 0;
$sep4 = 0;
$oct4 = 0;
$nov4 = 0;
$dec4 = 0;
$jan3 = 0;
$feb3 = 0;
$mar3 = 0;
$apr3 = 0;
$may3 = 0;
$jun3 = 0;
$jul3 = 0;
$aug3 = 0;
$sep3 = 0;
$oct3 = 0;
$nov3 = 0;
$dec3 = 0;
```

this is the most time consuming code when i try to make for example i want the default value of `$jan5` is equal to zero.. can some one teach me how to make this short? thank you so much for reading

```
$date = 'smi_initialdate';
$level = 'smi_level';
$year = '2012';

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT( $date, '%m' ) As monthz FROM eis_mngt_sales_iti WHERE year($date) = '$year' ORDER BY $date");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
$count++;


    if($row['smi_level']=='5star')
    {
        if($row['monthz']==1)
        {
        $jan++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==2)
        {
        $feb++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==3)
        {
        $mar++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==4)
        {
        $apr++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==5)
        {
        $may++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==6)
        {
        $jun++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==7)
        {
        $jul++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==8)
        {
        $aug++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==9)
        {
        $sep++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==10)
        {
        $oct++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==11)
        {
        $nov++;
        }elseif($row['monthz']==12)
        {
        $dec++;
        }
    }   
}
```

i decide to put this  `$jan5 = 0;$feb5 = 0;$mar5 = 0;$apr5 = 0;$may5 = 0;$jun5 = 0;$jul5 = 0;` so that if the data did not pass to this condition `if($row['smi_level']=='5star')` they have the return value of zero(0).

so that my output can adapt in this code

```
[<?php  echo$jan5.",".$feb5.",".$mar5.",".$apr5.",".$may5.",".$jun5.",".$jul5.",".$aug5.",".$sep5.",".$oct5.",".$nov5.",".$dec5;
?]
```

if a dont use the above code the `$jan5 = 0;$feb5 = 0;$mar5 = 0;$apr5 = 0;$may5 = 0;$jun5 = 0;$jul5 = 0;................` when i echo or print it i look like this
1,2,5,11,12 but with the use of that(the first sample code above) the output will be 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,11,12.

thank, sorry if this became confusing, sorry about my grammar

Comment: It's ok.  Not quite clear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to make default values for every date in the calendar year?

Comment: We need more information on what you are attempting to do.

Comment: This looks like a good case for an array and a loop, but it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: u mean guys you want my complete code?

Comment: i almost sure that you not need to setup so many variables with same names, try `$dates[$month][$day]=0;` don't froget that not all months have 30 days and here are some years when feb have 29 days

Comment: We'd like to know the goal of your code. You're trying to set jan5, feb5, mar5, etc to 0. Why?

Comment: ok ok w8 i will update my code thx guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do the trick...

```
$month = array('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec');
$day = array(3,4,5);

foreach($day as $d)
{
    foreach($month as $m)
    {
        ${$m.$d} = 0;
    }
}
```

But i recommend you to use **Array**.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly off of your question, but a suggested code improvement/revision:

```
    switch($row['monthz']){
      case 1:
        $jan++;
        break;

      case 2:
        $feb++;
        break;

      case 3:
        $mar++;
        break;

      case 4:
        $apr++;
        break;

      case 5:
        $may++;
        break;

      case 6:
[ ... ]
```

It looks just a bit cleaner, a bit less code. [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for more details.